# Parameter "unevaluatedValue" cannot be null when saving *.rptproj project

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

If you have existing Report Server Project in your solution and you upgrade SQL Server Data Tools from version 14.0.61707.300 to 14.0.61709.290, you can get  following message when opening your existing *.rptproj files:

[image: Upgrade message]

When you confirm upgrade by clicking on "Yes" button, solution could be successfully opened.
When you try to save modified project file, you can get SaveAs... dialog and following confirmation box:

[image: replace project file confirmation]

But when you confirm replacing existing project file, you could get an error from Visual Studio:
[image: Parameter "unevaluatedValue" cannot be null]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I found at [Community developer site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/121092/saving-updated-reporting-service-rptproj-throws-pa.html), the problem is in the content of project files. To solve the situation you have to open existing *.rptproj file and manually add **Platform** into all build configurations, where it is missing.

[image: Adding missing Platform element into project file]

After this change, Visual Studio detects that project files has been changed, so you can reload them and therefore you can save them.

Comment: All my platforms were already populated to Win32. I changed it to Win64 in Notepad, saved, switched back to VS, it asked me to reload the project/sln, it worked! I opened back up notepad, changed them all back to Win32, re-reloaded in VS and it still worked.